# French Schengen visa was refused. What are my options?

Tags: visa-refusals, schengen-visas

In the past 2 years I was granted 10 Schengen Visas from Belgium, Greece, Portugal, Switzerland and France (in December 2018)

In February 2019 I applied for a French Visa in the USA & was denied with the following reason:  "not convinced of your intention to return" to the USA.

The documents & purpose of the trip was the same in December 2018 and February 2019, no difference at all.  First visa was approved and I visited France & returned after 7 days, did not of course overstay my visa.

The second visa was refused!

1. Anyone experience the same situation?
2. What was the solution?
3. Should I re-apply?
4. Apply for another Schengen visa (not France)?
5. Appeal the decision?

Comment: They probably felt you were visiting too frequently. What was the purpose of your visits? If you have a girlfriend there, might be cause for suspicion.

Comment: Have your stays totaled 90 days or more in a span of 180 days?

Comment: @MatthewBarclay That's unlikely, there is a specific item on the refusal form for that.

Comment: The purported duplicate deals with egregious mistakes like forged documents and the like and mostly applies to initial applications. It doesn't contain any info on the specific question asked here.

Comment: Are you sure nothing changed in your plans or circumstances between the two applications? How long were your earlier stays?

Comment: What’s your nationality? What’s your status in the US? What’s your professional and family situation? What are your ties to the US? How did you demonstrate them? How long were the previous visas and trips? What is the reason for those numerous trips?

Comment: I am trying to understand why you have 10 previous Schengen visas in two years. Were each of these only granted as single-entry and/or less than usual 90/180 days? I think we can be more helpful if we know (1) what passport you carry, (2) your visa status in the USA, (3) the specifics of the Schengen visas you have been granted heretofore, and (4) the circumstances of so many frequent, short trips.

Comment: From Morocco and living in the USA for 23 years holding legal permanent resident (Green Card).  Married with 4 kids born and raised in the USA.  Have a good job for 20 years.  Last 10 visas granted were tourists for different countries in Europe.

Comment: Previous visas were valid form 1, 2, 3, and 6 months with 30-90 days stay.

Comment: Nothing changed in my life between December 2018 and February 2019:  Same 4 kids, wife, job and house and still Green Card holder for 23 years

Comment: No, I do not have a girlfriend or people to visit, I was traveling as a tourists with my US Citizens family members

Comment: The longest stay was 5-7 days in each visit.  Never overstayed or spent more than 90 days in each period.

Comment: Absolutely no forged documents, I worked for the same company for over 20 years, I provided a letter / paystubs from the company.

Comment: Most trips were short and/or 1-2 days transit while flying to non-europeans countries such as:  Morocco, Emarate, Turkey, Australia, South Korea and Japan.  I have 1 year visa for most Asian countries and Australia and New Zealand  (I am a big travelers along with my family)

Comment: Have you considered obtaining US citizenship? You are generally eligible after five years with a green card (3 years if you obtained it via marriage).

Answer (score 2):

An appeal is long and costly and very unlikely to succeed so I don't see the point here (earlier questions cover this). A fresh applications therefore seems like the only course of action available to visit the Schengen area but applying immediately in the exact same circumstances will attract a new refusal. The consulate is under no pressure to revise or justify their decision.

I think the most promising approach is to apply to another Schengen country but only after waiting several months. You must at all cost avoid giving the impression that you are trying to salvage this trip and circumvent the first decision. Plan a trip to another country, prepare a strong and credible travel plan and follow through on it. Additional short trips to other parts of the Schengen area should bolster your credibility and make it possible to reapply for a French visa in one or two years from now.

Comment: Are you sure the appeal cost money?  The form didn't mention any fees!  It only stated the reason of refusal and the address to mail the appeal.

Comment: Regarding my credible travel:  I've 1 year multiple visa for Australia, New Zealand and S. Korea along with Japan.  I am so confident that their feral was by error!  There is no way for me to leave my family, home, job and 20 years legal permanent residency to overstay my visa and live illegally in France, make no sense but I am not sure how they treated my 2nd application giving the fact 1st was approved

Comment: @TRAVELRING No, the appeal doesn't cost money but realistically you need a (French) lawyer. In all likelihood, the appeal will eventually be rejected anyway but long after the delay, the main reason you lodge an appeal is to be able to go to court afterwards.

Comment: @TRAVELRING I agree with you, it doesn't make much sense but that's not a credible travel plan. “Visiting Greek islands” is what I mean by a credible travel plan. The goal is to overcome the refusal by doing typical tourist stuff a few times before applying to France again.

Comment: I read few posts where the appeal was approved and visa was issued.

Comment: Yes, I was granted a Greek Visa and we visited the greek Islands!  All our trips are for tourism.

Comment: Visiting Sydney, Seoul and Tokyo is not a credible passed travel plan?

Comment: @TRAVELRING I am speaking about *future* travel. And what good is a plan to go to Sydney to apply for a Schengen visa? Again, not discussing your character, past travels, or links with your place of residence, which all seem very strong, I am just suggesting a strategy to overcome the refusal. Greek islands was just example, just make sure that future applications have similarly strong and credible plans.

Comment: @TRAVELRING Regarding appeals: In France? On the first appeal to the *Commission de recours contre les décisions de refus de visa d'entrée en France* or after a full-blown court case? For a visitor visa or another discretionary decision or for family visa or another as-of-right visa? Sure, they publish stats suggesting a few percents of the appeals succeed but not much.